# How to Convert Php Object to String?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to get string from database, I want to convert object from database Postgres to String what should I do?

```
public function gettable($username, $password){
    $cek_user = $this->db->query("SELECT hak_akses FROM tablelogin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = md5('$password')");  // Cek User Sudah Terdaftar
    if($cek_user->num_rows()>0){
        static $cek;
        foreach($cek_user->result() as $cek){
            $cek->hak_akses;
        }
        if($cek=='admin'){
            $ambil = $this->db->query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' and table_name != 'tablelogin'");
            return $ambil->result();
        }
        if($cek=='semi_admin'){
            $ambil = $this->db->query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' and table_name != 'tablelogin' and table_name != 'Film' and table_name != 'Hewan'");
            return $ambil->result();
        }
        if($cek == 'user'){
            $ambil = $this->db->query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' and table_name != 'tablelogin' and table_name != 'Gudang' and table_name != 'inventaris' and table_name != 'Pegawai'");
            return $ambil->result();
        }
    }
    else {
        $hasil = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to compare `$cek->hak_akses;` with `admin` or `semi_admin`  etc.Dont need to convert to string.use `row()` result set.And make use of `else if` statements .like this..

```
if($cek_user->num_rows()>0){

        $row = $cek_user->row();
        $cek =  $row ->hak_akses;

       if($cek=='admin'){
            $ambil = $this->db->query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' and table_name != 'tablelogin'");
            return $ambil->result();
        }
       else if($cek=='semi_admin'){
            $ambil = $this->db->query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' and table_name != 'tablelogin' and table_name != 'Film' and table_name != 'Hewan'");
            return $ambil->result();
        }
       else if($cek == 'user'){
            $ambil = $this->db->query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' and table_name != 'tablelogin' and table_name != 'Gudang' and table_name != 'inventaris' and table_name != 'Pegawai'");
            return $ambil->result();
        }
    }
    else {
        $hasil = null;
    }
```